# Determine whether rational coordinates are in the right Sierpinski triangle

Tags: code-golf, fractal, rational-numbers

The [Sierpinski triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle) is a set of points on the plane which is constructed by starting with a single triangle and repeatedly splitting all triangles into four congruent triangles and removing the centre triangle.  The right Sierpinski triangle has corners at `(0,0)`, `(0,1)` and `(1,0)`, and looks like this:

[image: Sierpinski triangle]

Some equivalent definitions of this set are as follows:

- Points in the `n`th iteration of the process described above, for all `n`.
- Points `(x,y)` with `0 <= x <= 1` and `0 <= y <= 1` such that for all positive integers `n`, the `n`th bit in the binary expansion of x and y are not both `1`.
- Let `T = {(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)}`

Let `f` be a function on sets of 2D points defined by the following:

`f(X) = {(0,0)} ∪ {(x+t)/2 | x∈X, t∈T}`

Then the right Sierpinski triangle is the [topological closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28topology%29) of the [least fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_fixed_point) (by set containment) of `f`.

- Let `S` be the square `{(x,y) | 0<=x<=1 and 0<=y<=1}`

Let `g(X) = S ∩ {(x+t)/2 | x∈(X), t∈T}` (where `T` is as defined above)

Then the right Sierpinski triangle is the greatest fixed point of `g`.

## Challenge

Write a program or function which accepts 4 integers, `a,b,c,d` and gives a truthy value if `(a/b,c/d)` belongs to the right Sierpinski triangle, and otherwise gives a falsey value.

## Scoring

This is a code golf.  Shortest code in bytes wins.

## Test cases

The following are in the right Sierpinski triangle:

```
0 1 0 1
0 1 12345 123456
27 100 73 100
1 7 2 7
8 9 2 21
8 15 20 63
-1 -7 2 7
```

The following are not in the right Sierpinski triangle:

```
1 1 1 1
-1 100 1 3
1 3 1 3
1 23 1 7
4 63 3 66
58 217 4351 7577
-1 -7 3 7
```

Comment: Is `-1 -3 1 1` a valid input?

Comment: Yes, that is a valid input.  I've added test cases to make this clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Python 2, 68

```python
lambda n,d,N,D:1>=n/d>=0<=N/D<=1and(n<<abs(D*d))/d&(N<<abs(D*d))/D<1
```

A nice way to check for gasket membership made ugly. If we were guaranteed that the inputs are non-negative and in the unit square, we would have 38:

```
lambda n,d,N,D:(n<<D*d)/d&(N<<D*d)/D<1
```

The idea is that we check whether a point lies within the gasket by checking whether their binary fraction expansions bitwise-AND to 0. To get the first `k` character of the expansion, we bit-shift the numerator `k` bits left before integer-dividing by the denominator. We need to make `k` sufficiently large to catch a repeat. We note that the binary expansion `n/d` has period at most `d`, so the joint expansions have period at most `d*D`, so `k=d*D` suffices.

The rest is to check whether the fraction is in the box and insulate against inputs given like `-1/-3`.